# If $f''(x) + f'(x)g(x) - f(x) = f(a) = f(b) = 0$, then $f = 0$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, maxima-minima, extreme-value-theorem

Let $f, g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, with $f$ twice differentiable, and $f(a) = f(b) = 0, a \leq b$.  Show that if $f''(x) + f'(x)g(x) - f(x) = 0$, then $f = 0$ on $[a,b]$.  (*Source: Spivak Calculus.*)

My proof is below.  I request verification, critique, and suggestions.  *Note: Proofs are available; this question is to verify* my *proof.*

---

Since no conditions are specified on $g$, the equation $f''(x) + f'(x)g(x) - f(x) = 0$ simply means that for all $x$, $$[f'(x) = 0] \implies f''(x) = f(x) \tag{*}.$$

We claim that $f([a,b]) \leq 0$. By the Extreme Value Theorem, $f$ has a maximum at $c \in [a,b]$.  If $c = a \lor c = b$ we are done.  Otherwise, $c$ is a local maximum, so $f'(c) = 0$ and $f''(c) < 0$, and by $(*)$, $f(x) < 0$.

A similar argument shows that $f([a,b]) \geq 0$, completing the proof.

Additional question: Is this result of any significance or application elsewhere?

---

*Thank you for the feedback, which I'm using to rewrite the proof for clarity.  Also see my comment that this type of critique and revision, even if it doesn't change the functional equivalence of the proof, is still very important and is* not *a duplicate.*

We claim that $f([a,b]) \leq 0$.  By the Extreme Value Theorem, $f$ has a maximum at $c \in [a,b]$. If $c=a \lor c=b$ we are done. Otherwise, $c$ is a local maximum, so $f′(c)=0$ and $f′′(c)<0$.

Since no conditions are specified on $g$, the equation $f′′(x)+f′(x)g(x)−f(x)=0$ simply means that for any $y$ where $f′(y)=0$, then $f′′(y)=f(y)$.  Thus, since $f''(c) < 0$, then $f(c) < 0$.

A similar argument shows that $f([a,b]) \geq 0$, completing the proof.

Comment: Basically, your mistake is to say that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$; you cannot conclude that. But, at the point $c$ you can conclude that $f''(x)=f(x)$ and that is all you actually need. See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450879/spivak-calculus-f-satisfies-fxfxgx-fx-0-for-some-g-prove-that. 
$$\,$$
To elaborate: If the problem stated that _for every_ $g$ you had $f''(x)+g(x)f'(x)-f(x)=0$ then you would of course set $g(x)=0$ and conclude $f''(x)=f(x)$. However, the problem actually says that _there exists_ function $g$ with that property, and you cannot tell anything about it.

Comment: I never stated that $f'(x) = 0$ for all x, only that, when it does equal 0, it implies... I've added brackets to make that clearer.

Comment: It could maybe be clearer if instead of giving (*) first, you just point out that $f'(c)=0$ implies $f''(c)=f(c)$.

Comment: @SRobertJames, your question is a duplicate, so you should delete it. Look at the following link: [Spivak Calculus: $f$ satisfies $f''(x)+f'(x)g(x)-f(x)=0$, for some g. Prove that if  is 0 at two points, then  is 0 on the interval between them.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450879/spivak-calculus-f-satisfies-fxfxgx-fx-0-for-some-g-prove-that)

Comment: @Angelo: Rather than ask the OP to delete their post, simply vote to close the post at a duplicate.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I have already voted to close the post as it is a duplicate.

Comment: @SRobertJames: It appears that your copy of the question from Spivak has a flaw. In particular, you did not say how $g$ is quantified.

Comment: @Angelo OP is asking for verification of their solution, not necessarily other solutions

Comment: @bb_823, the OP duplicated not only the question but also the solution. For that reason I have already voted to close his post.

Comment: @SRobertJames Brackets definitely help. They have turned something that looked like $(\forall x)f'(x)=0\implies(\text{I am lazy to write }\forall x\text{ again})f''(x)=f(x)$ into something that looks a _bit_ more like $(\forall x)(f'(x)=0\implies f''(x)=f(x))$. So, if you want any takeaways from me: _make it unambiguous what your quantifiers are applied to_. Otherwise your proof is the same as the one in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Sometimes people don't care enough about quantifiers, are lazy, or don't understand them. I think your problem might be different, and that is that you really seem to have wanted to switch from English to mathematical notation. Had you just said something like "whenever $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$, it is also true that $f''(x)=f(x)$ for the same $x$" (pure English) or $(\forall x)(f'(x)=0\implies f''(x)=f(x))$ (pure math), everything would've been completely clear.

Comment: @LeeMosher Spivak simply states that a function $g$ exists, which I believe is included in my statement "Let $f, g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$".

Comment: @Angelo While you may be right that once understood, the proof I came up with is functionally equivalent to the one from the solution manual you linked to, verifying that itself is the point of the question.  Witness that a. there was helpful discussion _here_ (but not _there_) about the use of quantifiers whereas b. the proof _there_ was labeled "terse to the point that [readers] don't understand how the desired result ensues from it" which does _not_ seem to be a flaw with my exposition.  I'm adding the `proof-writing` tag to highlight this.

Comment: @aschepler Changed accordingly, and I think you're right that it's much clearer now.  How did you realize that this order would be clearer? I ask so I can make similar revisions in the future.

Comment: @SRobertJames I think this change relates to the question of whether a proof should reflect the thinking process that got you there, or the simplest steps that logically demonstrate the proof. Both are valuable, depending on context, and both have drawbacks. Sometimes textbook authors will point out some considerations and inspirations first, and then get into the detailed proof.

Comment: @aschepler Valuable advice! When writing a proof, consider two sequences: Start with the key insight vs start with the most direct logical argument.